# why is $f_{n}\rightarrow f \; \text{point-wise} \iff \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}=f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, limsup-and-liminf, sequence-of-function

in a proof of a lemma that states the following : $f_{n}\rightarrow f \; \text{point-wise} \implies f \; \text{is measurable} $

the author proceeded in 3 steps :

1. proving that $\sup_nf_n\;\text{&}\; \inf_nf_n$ are both measurable
2. proving that $\lim\sup_nf_n\;\text{&}\; \lim\inf_nf_n$ are both measurable
3. concluding from the following claim that $ f \; \text{is measurable}$

   $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}=f$$

I know that $\lim f_n = f$ but couldn't prove the above statement that I've never come across till this day.

if anybody could prove or explain why does that equivalence hold it'd be great.

thanks!

Comment: Can you prove the following for a sequence $a_n$? Namely $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a \Longleftrightarrow \limsup a_n = \liminf a_n = a$$

Comment: And then $f_n(x)$ is just a sequence once you fix $x$. So the above statement holds for $f_n$ as well.

Comment: I have an idea about the proof since $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ means every sub-sequence converges to $a$
and  $ \limsup a_n$ and $\liminf a_n $ are just the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of sub-sequential limits

then that equivalence should hold

Comment: You are done, my friend! Pointwise convergence means for a fixed $x$ the **sequence of numbers** $f_n(x)$ converges to some value. And that gives you the result that you have asked for. Btw $\liminf f_n(x)$ is also the pointwise $\liminf$

Comment: You can probably have a look at some older posts limit vs. limsup/liminf here on the site. For example: [Prove that a sequence converges to a finite limit iff lim inf equals lim sup](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325793) or [Show that if the sequence$(x_n)$ is bounded, then $(x_n)$ converges iff $\lim\sup(x_n)=\lim\inf(x_n)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/432163)

Comment: @rapidracim...In your question ,the functions are measurable with repsect to which measure?

Comment: @MariosGretsas they are functions that maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\overline{ \mathbb{R} }$ both are equipped with the sigma algebra generated by the union of their associated borel-sigma algebra with the set of all negligible sets and the measure used is just the usual Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we prove that $\inf_n f_n(x)$ and $\sup_nf_n(x)$ are measurable then  we can  can prove that $\lim\sup_n f_n(x)=\inf_n \sup_{m \geq n}f_m(x)$ and $\lim \inf_n f_n(x)=\sup_n \inf_{m \geq n}f_m(x)$ are measurable.

Thus the function $f(x)=\lim\sup_n f_n(x)=\lim\inf_n f_n(x)=\lim f_n(x)$ will be measurable,because the set $$\{x:\limsup_n f_n(x)>a\}$$ $$=\{x:\lim \inf_n f_n(x)>a\}$$ $$=\{x:\lim_nf_n(x)\}$$ $$=\{x:f(x)>a\}$$ would be measurable $\forall a \in \Bbb{R}$